# The horizontal movement stops working after I add the CameraFollow script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am creating a 2D game and I have, for now, three main scripts: one for vertical movement for free falling, one for horizontal movement and a Camera Follow script. Whenever I attach the target object to the Camera Follow script, the horizontal movement stops working, while the vertical one is fine. What could be the problem here?

HorizontalMovement:

```
public class HorizontalMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float horizontalBoundary = 3.5f; // Maximum left and right boundaries for the object

    void Update()
    {
        // Horizontal movement (left and right)
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Clamp the object's position to stay within the horizontal boundaries
        float clampedXPosition = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -horizontalBoundary, horizontalBoundary);
        transform.position = new Vector3(clampedXPosition, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Camera Follow;

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target; // Reference to the falling object's Transform
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0f, 0f, -10f); // Adjust the camera's offset if needed

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            // Update the camera's position to match the falling object's position
            transform.position = target.position + offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Vertical Movement:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    public float fallSpeed = 3f; // Speed at which the object falls

    void Update()
    {

        // Vertical falling movement
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I tried everything I could, as in thinking maybe an Update instead of LateUpdate would work, tried attaching other targets and everything's fine except for this one.

Comment: Please also show the vertical one, and clarify which objects these scripts are attached.

Comment: I am trying to atatch the CameraFollow script to the MainCamera and the Horizontal + Vertical Movement to a 2D capsule that represents the falling object.

Comment: Are you sure the target is not moving horizontally or does it appear that the target has not moved because the target and camera are relatively stationary?

Comment: So, I just noticed that, the target changes the X position in the Inspector when I try to move, but not visually.

Comment: Could you please use a more descriptive title? e.g. `the horizontal movement stops working, while the vertical one is fine.` already summarizes the issue way better than  `There is a problem with the CameraFollow script` ;)

Comment: `but not visually` - as @shingo commented your camera follows the exact position of the object so it wouldn't visually change the position on the screen

Comment: So, in order to make that work, I could fix the camera on the X axis, allowing it to just follow the object on the Y axis.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you for your help!